# read_timeout in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, nokogiri

I'm fetching some weather data from an online xml doc using Nokogiri, and I would like to set up a timeout for graceful recovery in case the source can't be reached...

My google searches show several possible methods for open-uri and Net::HTTP, but none specific to Nokogiri. My attempts to use those methods are failing (not too surprisingly):

```
begin
currentloc = ("http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query=" + @destination.weatherloc)
currentloc.read_timeout = 10 # 
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(currentloc))
rescue Timeout::Error
  return "Current weather for this location not available: request timed out."
end
```

returns "NoMethodError", and:

```
begin
currentloc = ("http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query=" + @destination.weatherloc)
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(currentloc), :read_timeout => 10)
rescue Timeout::Error
  return "Current weather for this location not available: request timed out."
end
```

returns "TypeError can't convert Hash into String"

Does Nokogiri support this kind of method (and if so... how?), or should I be looking at some other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the timeout module :

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'timeout'

begin
  timeout(10) do
    result = Nokogiri::XML(open(currentloc))
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  return "Current weahter..."
end
```

Comment: This appears to work (at least it doesn't break), but when I try to test it by disconnecting eth0, I'm getting a SocketError. I guess I need some sort of conditional test for that, too.

Adding an extra rescue statement (rescue SocketError) is failing, however.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code so I can see for myself in greater detail?